# Most efficient way to remove duplicated code from multiple strategies

Tags: java, spring, oop, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

We have 3 types of attributes in our project: **CategoryAttribute**, **ProductAttribute** and **ProductTypeAttribute**. These are outside of our control as they come from autogenerated classes and may contain attribute values of different types e.g. **text**, **number** or **image**. Now, each attribute has its own strategy to retrieve attributeValue. For simplicity, let's assume that all 3 of them have **TextStrategy**, **NumberStrategy** and **ImageStrategy**.

Example strategy:

```
@Component
public class CategoryImageAttributeStrategy implements CategoryAttributeStrategy {

  @Override
  public boolean isApplicable(CategoryAttribute attribute) {
      return attribute.getImage() != null;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getAttributeValue(CategoryAttribute attribute) {
      //return attribute value here 
      //may be different or may be the same 
      //for ProductImageAttributeStrategy and ProductTypeImageAttributeStrategy
  }
```

}

While getting image value may be different for all of them, getting text value is the same and we end up with 3 classes of almost the same code and I really really really don't like duplicating code.

I thought about creating an abstract class/default interface for each strategy type e.g. **DefaultTextStrategy** that all 3 text strategies would inherit from and either use default code provided higher or override it with own implementation, however I'm not really satisfied with this approach as it requires to create even more classes for such a simple task.

Maybe is it even possible to combine strategies of the same type (e.g. image) into one?

I would really like to hear what more experienced folks have to say in this matter as I would like to learn and improve.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

First, I created an interface for all types of strategies named "**AttributeValueStrategy**". Then added **3 callbacks** (type specific, e.g. NumberValueCallback etc.). Now, each strategy implements callback interface of its type and AttributeValueStrategy interface. Then there's **DefaultStrategyMethods** class that contains default "getAtrribute" for each type and the actual strategy call the defaultStrategyMethods (like below) or just implements its own code.

```
@Override
public Object getAttributeValue(Object attribute) {
    return defaultStrategyMethods.getNumberValue(attribute, this);
}
```

Callbacks are created because only the actual strategy knows which class should it cast to (and has a method to do that), and DefaultStrategyMethods needs to use it so that's why I pass "this" as second argument (which is the callback itself).

No more duplicates, everything is clear and clean.

Answer (score 0):

There should be only 3 strategies. TextStrategy, NumberStrategy and ImageStrategy which extend the base strategy. Mixing attributes and strategy will make it confusing as both are actually independent and have many to many relationship with one another.

Let the 3 attributes extend a single Attribute class : CategoryAttribute, ProductAttribute and ProductTypeAttribute.

Let the strategies decide on what needs to be done based on the Attribute class object being passed to it. For Text strategy there would be single implementation. For Image strategy, you may require special handling for the one class.

Comment: The problem is (as I mentioned in the original post) that CategoryAttribute, ProductAttribute etc. are autogenerated classes based on xsd schema and I have no control over them, so I can't make them extend something else. I like the idea of 3 strategies only tho, but in the strategy class I would have to take Object argument and check its instanceof.(to find out what attribute type it is) which would look a bit dirty. At least I think that isApplicable method with 3 instanceof's is kinda meh.